# Magento apply discount coupons

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to apply coupon code in magento landing page , i just saw the code, but according to code, the code apply on cart's amount and after deducting coupon code, it apply the price on cart, but i want to apply code on a specific static price, can it be possible? if yes, then please help me to solve it out.
Thanks

Comment: are you need auto discount apply on cart page for specific price right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to apply discount on product level:

Default magento have this feature:

**Magento Admin->Promotions-> Catalog Price Rules**

This URL may help: http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules